# Bootstrap align item in same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how to align 12 items on the same line without overlapping using Bootstrap, this is the first time I use it.

Thanks in advance.

**html**

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h1 class="text-center">Accueil</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <mat-card class="text-center">Toutes les Nations</mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <mat-card>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2" *ngFor="let post of postArray">
            <div *ngIf="post.id <= 12">
              <img src="/assets/flags/{{ post.bigramme }}.jpg" alt="flag" style="width: 1.4rem;">
              {{post.libelle}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <mat-card>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2" *ngFor="let post of postArray">
            <div *ngIf="post.id >= 13">
              <img src="/assets/flags/{{ post.bigramme }}.jpg" alt="flag" style="width: 1.4rem;">
              {{post.libelle}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `col-1` instead of `col-2`.
You might need to make things extremelly small, but is this what you mean ?
(View it in `Full page` mode)

**-- Edited base on comments --**

```css
.country {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 px-0">
      <span class="country">Country</span>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/10x6/ccc/000" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help how to get the text on the left and the image on the right please

Comment: @toto You can just change the `img` tag order in the HTML. I updated the answer for reference.